# Joomla - Get Latest Version Zip Link - scrip Install

Tags: joomla, ansible

Does Joomla have a Link to the Latest Version? Wordpress for example has a link to https://wordpress.org/latest.zip , so I know I can always download that zip and get the latest version.

I am working on ansible script to automatically setup a server and install joomla and I need to keep it simple so I would like to spesify a link or api call or something to always get the latest joomla version zip.

Any help appreciated.
David

Comment: WHY would anyone DOWNVOTE this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question - it is certainly not as easy as wordpress.

You can download the latest version using ansible in the following way:

Download the XML file you mentioned to your local machine:

```
   - name: download latest joomla packages list to local machine
     tags: joomlanew
     get_url:
       url: https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml
       dest: "{{ role_path }}/scripts/extension_sts.xml"
       force: yes
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Run a python script to parse this XML to find the latest package zip file:

```
   - name: find latest joomla version
     tags: joomlanew
     command: python ./latest_joomla.py
     args:
       chdir: "{{ role_path }}/scripts"
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
     register: xmlresp
```

You can then use {{ xml.resp.stdout }} in ansible as the input for your download code:

```
- name: download & unzip joomla
  tags: joomlanew
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ xmlresp.stdout }}"
    dest: /home/username/public_html/
    remote_src: yes
    mode: 0755
```

FYI the code in th python script to parse the XML would be:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('extension_sts.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('downloadurl')
last=(len(itemlist))-1
print (itemlist[last].firstChild.data)
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you for this script. I home someone will make a service that does this for us automatically - we should submit a feature / but report

Comment: Feature request made - https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/18401

Comment: Cool. Yeah agree it should be a feature really, especially since we don't know if the XML file format will change, which could break this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some digging I guess the best way to go after this is the way Joomla Core does it:

1. Get detailsurl out of Last entry out of the Joomla Core Update site (https://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml) - in this instance https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml
2. Get downloadurl out of Last entry out of the url you got in step 1 - in this instance - you need to make sure this is not a PATCH url but UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to download the latest version: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/archive/staging.zip

Comment: Thanks you, this is more in the correct direction but I rather want a stable release archive rather than a staging version - any idea?